# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: reactjs, json

Its my first time posting please help. I deploy this project on render.com then error happen. It works locally but in hosting site its not. Please help thank you for all responses.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useAuthContext } from './useAuthContext';

export const useLogin = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null);
  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext();

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const response = await fetch('/api/skilledInfo/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(json.error);
    }
    if (response.ok) {
      // save the user to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(json));

      // update the auth context
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: json });

      // update loading state
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { login, isLoading, error };
};
```

Here is the error
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz7iC.png) then the code'const json = await response.json();' highlighted.

If I understand correctly this code return promise object and I need to turn it into JSON. But I do not know how. Please help

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example of a json you try to parse.

Comment: "email": "ricky45@gmail.com",
    "skilledInfo": {
        "_id": "6399d3a3fe6bbd6b79e4fa88",
        "email": "ricky45@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$dvrfRJZeMPDFehnlUri9fu7TmyAPA9ekxw3AUnICd2mQf8Bqnx6gq",
        "fname": "Patrick",
        "mname": "Mendiola",
        "lname": "Mirandna",
        "createdAt": "2022-12-14T13:46:11.097Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-14T13:46:11.097Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2Mzk5ZDNhM2ZlNmJiZDZiNzllNGZhODgiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzEzNzUzNjEsImV4cCI6MTY3MTYzNDU2MX0.aHUCc0HxqNE0Jdd4nb03"

Comment: "email": "ricky45@gmail.com", "skilledInfo": { "_id": "6399d3a3fe6bbd6b79e4fa88", "email": "ricky45@gmail.com", "password": "$2b$10$dvrfRJZeMPDFehnlUri9fu7TmyAPA9ekxw3AUnICd2mQf8Bqnx6gq", "fname": "Patrick", "mname": "Mendiola", "lname": "Mirandna", "createdAt": "2022-12-14T13:46:11.097Z", "updatedAt": "2022-12-14T13:46:11.097Z", "__v": 0 }, "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2Mzk5ZDNhM2ZlNmJiZDZiNzllNG"@Teddy

Comment: Well that would not be valid json. It needs `{}` around the entire content. like this:
`{
  "email": "ricky45@gmail.com",
  "skilledInfo": {
    "_id": "6399d3a3fe6bbd6b79e4fa88",
    "email": "ricky45@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2b$10$dvrfRJZeMPDFehnlUri9fu7TmyAPA9ekxw3AUnICd2mQf8Bqnx6gq",
    "fname": "Patrick",
    "mname": "Mendiola",
    "lname": "Mirandna",
    "createdAt": "2022-12-14T13:46:11.097Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-14T13:46:11.097Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2Mzk5ZDNhM2ZlNmJiZDZiNzllNG"
}`

Comment: How can i fix that?

Comment: The source of the json is from your code right?

Comment: here is the postman request result https://photos.app.goo.gl/4oVt8DTgiTfTns966

Comment: @Adnarim it has to do with your `api` deployment... your `ajax request` has failed already, and you were trying to parse it's `body`

Comment: i have tested your scenario locally with a flask api and i had no issues. Also i can see from your screenshot that the json that is sent has `{}` around it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/3yaHWZdH0FM this vid is my reference to learn where part should i change or need to study Im a beginner so I just follow when trying to learn new things